# Python non-blocking SSL socket unwrap: how to detect completion of shutdown handshake?

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

Given a non-blocking socket...

```
import asyncio
import socket

server_sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
server_sock.setblocking(False)
server_sock.bind(('', port))
server_sock.listen(socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
sock, _ = await loop.sock_accept(server_sock)
```

... that is wrapped with ssl...

```
import ssl
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(f'ssl.crt', keyfile=f'ssl.key')
ssl_sock = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True, do_handshake_on_connect=False)
```

... and has had the setup handshake performed by `do_handshake` and a loop...

```
while True:
    try:
        ssl_sock.do_handshake()
        break
    except (ssl.SSLWantReadError, ssl.SSLWantWriteError):
        # We could have something more efficient, e.g. doing things
        # with the readers/writers, but it works
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

... and then the `unwrap` method called to initiate the shutdown handshake...

```
try:
    ssl_sock.unwrap()
except (SSLWantReadError, SSLWantWriteError):
    pass
```

... then how can I wait for completion of the shutdown handshake? So I can write something like...

```
await ssl_shutdown_handshake_complete()
```

?

Comment: `wrap_socket` is likely not the intended way to use asyncio with SSL - the initial loop consisting of `try/except` and `asyncio.sleep(0)` looks like trouble. Can you use [`asyncio.start_server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.start_server) and pass an SSL context as the `ssl` keyword argument?

Comment: I think that you should be able to use wrap socket with a non blocking socket / asyncio: I think it was sorted around https://bugs.python.org/issue1251
, with an example at https://github.com/crazyguitar/pysheeet/blob/master/docs/notes/python-asyncio.rst#simple-https-web-server-low-level-api (admittedly not using the sleep). `asyncio.start_server` is a bit awkward for my case since I'm upgrading the connection to TLS after some non-encrypted communication: https://bugs.python.org/issue34975 . However, I am curious to know if the `asyncio.start_server` method has a way of waiting for shutdown.

Comment: I now see the problem, and that's a major use case for SSL. Have you seen [this] (http://blog.povilasb.com/posts/opportunistic-tls-with-python-asyncio/) post? Also, the implementation of the ssl transport in asyncio seems to have a shut-down method with a callback notifying that the shutdown is complete. If you can get something similar, then you can easily turn it into await by creating a future, initiate the shutdown with `future.set_result(None)` as the callback, and awaiting the future. Good luck!

Comment: @user4815162342 Ah that's helpful... although I have to admit I'm a bit skeptical about coupling really heavily to the asyncio server/transport/protocol framework. It somehow feels a bit inflexible...

Comment: Agreed about the sentiment - hopefully you can make the transport stuff work as part of the stream implementation and (once you've made it work) never look at it again.